# How to denote isomorphism/ ring direct product

Tags: direct-product, module-isomorphism

Assume a ring $R$ is isomorphic to direct product of $F_1,F_2,F_3$

We can denote this by

$R\cong F_1\times F_2 \times F_3$

Is this equivalent to

$R\cong F_1\oplus F_2 \oplus F_3$
???

Comment: Use $\times$ in that first line instead of $\otimes$ (which is something else, namely a tensor product)

Comment: As Mark said, don't use $\otimes$, use $\times$. As far as the content of your question, the direct product and direct sum amount to the same thing when you have finitely many terms.

Comment: Thanks all, I should have use $\times$ instead of $\otimes$